How to show an alert when I click on a menu item?
I have a windowless application and I’d like to show an alert message when the user clicks a button in the menu (it’s more complex than that, actually). I’ve tried the following code:
import SwiftUI
@main
struct MyAwesomeApplication: App {
  @State var showErrorMessage: Bool = false
  var body: some Scene {
    Settings {
      MyAwesomeSettingsView()
    }
    .commands {
      CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
        Button("Danger, Will Robinson") {
          showErrorMessage = true
        }
        .alert("Danger!", isPresented: $showErrorMessage, actions: {
          Button("OK") {
            showErrorMessage = false
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}


I've also tried putting the button in its own view, with no success.
As I’m still learning Swift I wonder if I’m going the wrong way…
Thanks for pointing me any directions.

You can use NSAlert which creates the window on your behalf, or create a window yourself.

@vadian Using NSAlert worked, thank you!
